# vb.net overflow of variable as in c#

Tags: vb.net, cryptography, overflow

I need to make some big multiplications for cryptographic reasons in vb.net and overflow the variable as C,C++ and C# does. I have disabled the check of overflow at the vb.net project but when i an doing those multiplications i get as a result 1.#INF

ex. in c:

```
z^y= 0xFFFFFFFF ^ 0x000003FC= 0xFFFFFC03
```

in vb.net:

```
z^y= 0xFFFFFFFF ^ 0x000003FC= 1.#INF
```

is it possible to be done?

Comment: That's not legal VB.Net code.  VB uses &H prefix for hex numbers

Comment: Do it in C#. You are just going to be lured into traps by doing it in VB.net. Too many operators/functions that look alike, but really arent ... (if, IIF etc ...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` in C is `Xor` in VB and should never be able to overflow.

On the other hand, if you write `^` in VB then this is assumed to be the “power” operation.

```
Dim z = &HFFFFFFFF
Dim y = &H000003FC
Dim x = z Xor y
```